# Parsing RSS XML feed into a listview

Tags: java, android

Getting straight to the point, I'm  new to this and trying to use this https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library library to parse an rss feed and put all that into a listview. (I don't mind if you give me an alternate solution to this though. I picked this simply because it looked like it would be easier to understand and less work....)

MY problem is that I'm not sure how to do it, and when I read up on it on google it's either darn confusing or Eclipse says there's something wrong with it and gives me an error.

So :: can someone please explain to me, how I should go about doing this. I understand how to put a URL into this feed, and generally how listviews work,

but I'm getting stumped on passing the data that the library extracts from the feed and passing it into my listview. I don't have a clue how to write out java code that tells it to take data that this library passed and say, put it into this string.

I'm also confused about how a listadapter / adapter works. I think I understand how to write it, but all my past attempts have given me errors and I'm not sure what's the problem there.

It would also be nice if someone could explain how the list_layout thing works out. By that, I mean when you create a new xml file and define how one row of the listview looks, but I don't see how it gets linked up with the main xml file with a single listview.

Thanks for helping me out - it's a school project....

(btw, please be simple with the explanations. I think the main problem i'm having is that a lot of the tutorials like using very technical language, and it ends up not getting the point across to me. Even if you give me a chunk of code, and tell me all that parses my url, that's all i need.)

Answer (score 1):

A ListView needs an Adapter to know what the data is and how much of the data there is. The ListView asks the adapter for a view to display a single item using the adapter's method getView(....). In this method you should inflate your view (the item) using the getLayoutInflater().inflate(..). You then get a view for which you can get the specific sub-views by using the findViewById(...) method on that view. Of each sub-view you set the value of a part of your item.

In order to avoid having to inflate a view for each and every item the ListView recycles item views whenever possible, therefore the method getView(...) receives a view, if that view is not null you can use that view instead of inflating a new view.

While reading your data, or when you have read all your data, you need to tell the adapter that the data has changed, which then tells your ListView that it needs to redisplay data. You tell your adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged().

There is a Google I/O session on the ListView, maybe that might be interesting to watch: http://www.google.com/intl/nl/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Answer (score 0):

In you android-sdk under /samples/android-xx/ there is a sample called "XmlAdapter" which contains a RSS-feed activity. Could be a helpful alternative.